# How to arrange three ggplot2 plots with the same size

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have 3 plot that I want to arrange in 2 rows, 1 column, and all present the same size.

My problem is that the 3rd (row 2) plot present legend that is common to all plots, and it make just a little bit small that the rest.

```
library(phyloseq)
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

data("GlobalPatterns")
GP <- GlobalPatterns
GP.ord <- ordinate(GP, "NMDS", "bray", k=3)
DF_ord <- plot_ordination(GP, GP.ord, axes=c(1:3), justDF = TRUE)
```

head(DF_ord)

```
             NMDS1      NMDS2       NMDS3 X.SampleID  Primer Final_Barcode Barcode_truncated_plus_T Barcode_full_length SampleType
CL3     -0.2128261  0.7818086 -1.12967604        CL3 ILBC_01        AACGCA                   TGCGTT         CTAGCGTGCGT       Soil
CC1     -0.5826017  0.7847393 -0.83925680        CC1 ILBC_02        AACTCG                   CGAGTT         CATCGACGAGT       Soil
SV1     -0.4011154  1.1073660 -0.90078134        SV1 ILBC_03        AACTGT                   ACAGTT         GTACGCACAGT       Soil
M31Fcsw  2.2390139 -0.1076734  0.03626119    M31Fcsw ILBC_04        AAGAGA                   TCTCTT         TCGACATCTCT      Feces
M11Fcsw  2.1733638 -0.2290418  0.33818019    M11Fcsw ILBC_05        AAGCTG                   CAGCTT         CGACTGCAGCT      Feces
M31Plmr  0.1611431  1.3583510  0.67498162    M31Plmr ILBC_07        AATCGT                   ACGATT         CGAGTCACGAT       Skin
```

Generate the plots

Plot1

```
p1 <- ggplot(DF_ord, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", size = 0.5, color= "#999999") +               
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", size = 0.5, color= "#999999") +   
    geom_point( aes(colour= SampleType), size = 3.5, alpha=0.7) + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Plot2

```
p2 <- ggplot(DF_ord, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS3)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", size = 0.5, color= "#999999") +               
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", size = 0.5, color= "#999999") +   
    geom_point( aes(colour= SampleType), size = 3.5, alpha=0.7) + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Plot3

```
p3 <- ggplot(DF_ord, aes(x = NMDS2, y = NMDS3)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", size = 0.5, color= "#999999") +               
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", size = 0.5, color= "#999999") +   
    geom_point( aes(colour= SampleType), size = 3.5, alpha=0.7) + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Eliminate the legend for p1 and p2

```
p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.position = "none")
p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Arrange the 3 plots

```
top_row = ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, labels = c("A)", "B)"))

bottom_row = ggarrange(NULL, p3, NULL, ncol = 3, labels = c("", "C)", ""), widths = c(1,2,1))

 myplot <- ggarrange(top_row, bottom_row, ncol = 1)
```

The top_row plots are little bit bigger (rectangle) than the bottom_row plot (square) !!

myplot

[image]

How to make all plots with the same size (square), and keep the legend common to all in the botton_row plot ?

Comment: If you want to fix the aspect ratio of the plot area, you can add `coord_fixed()` to your plot code for each plot.  You may have to define the heights/ratios, but at least all plots should be square.

Comment: If the legend is common, you can look at the package **lemon**. it has a specific function to accomodate that. Also, you can use the package **patchwork** to arrange your plots in the canvas. It has a specific function to "draw" an empty plot to align stuff around. Add a reproducible example for us to work on.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to "fake a legend" like in this example:

```
p1 <- iris |> 
  ggplot2::ggplot(
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(
      x = Sepal.Length,
      y = Sepal.Width,
      color = Species
    )
  ) +
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none")

p4 <- iris |>
  dplyr::count(Species) |> # no overplotting
  ggplot2::ggplot(
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(
      x = 0,
      y = Species,
      color = Species,
      label = Species
    )
  ) +
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::theme_void() +
  ggplot2::geom_text(x = 0.1,
    color = "#000000", hjust = "left") + 
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggplot2::xlim(-1,1)



lay <- rbind(
  c(1,2),
  c(3,4)
)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  p1,
  p1,
  p1,
  p4,
  layout_matrix = lay
)
```